# jQuery - Change Image and Hide

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wanting to have two separate lists which are images. They are wrapped inside two separate div's with classes "web" and "nonweb". I want two buttons at the top.

When the "Website Design" button is clicked, all the "nonweb" content disappears, and the "web" content appears. The "Website Design" image also changes to a different one. I will have two buttons, a "Website Design" and "Non Website Design". Upon loading the page, they will both be in their black and white form. When clicking one, the opposite buttons content will remain hidden, and the buttons linked content will appear. The clicked button will also change to a brighter one.

If the other button is clicked, all of the opposite button's content will hide itself, and the other button will change back to the black and white version, whilst the clicked button changes, and it's content appears, yada yada yada.

I've been woring on it a while, and cannot seem to find the correct way to do it.
Check this pastie for a slightly more detailed version with code:

http://pastie.org/private/6b5voiypsdbzfnjogj77g

Thank you!

Comment: Please make jsfiddle.net example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this, please be aware I'm a first year at university ><

Should do as you wanted, just change the URLs to your needs.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.nonweb").hide(); // hide nonweb content by default
    $("div.web").hide(); // hide web content by default

    $("img.webdesigntop").click(function(){
        $("img.webdesigntop").attr("src", "http://www.plaatsoft.nl/wp-content/uploads/RedSquare.jpg"); // color webdesigntop button
        $("img.nonwebdesigntop").attr("src", "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1287988344/blue-square_normal.jpg"); //grayscale nonwebdesigntop button
        $("div.nonweb").hide("fast"); // hide nonweb content
        $("div.web").show("slow"); // show web content
    });

    $("img.nonwebdesigntop").click(function(){
        $("img.webdesigntop").attr("src", "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1287988344/blue-square_normal.jpg"); //grayscale webdesigntop button
        $("img.nonwebdesigntop").attr("src", "http://www.plaatsoft.nl/wp-content/uploads/RedSquare.jpg"); //colour nonwebdesigntop button
        $("div.web").hide("fast"); // hide web content
        $("div.nonweb").show("slow"); // show nonweb content
    });
});
</script>
```